# Whats the best way to make an unordered lists of reverse chronological dates in asp.net 2.0 with vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime, dynamic

I need to create an unordered list of dates for a news items archive... It should look like this

```
2011
    Dec
    Nov
    etc..
2010
    Dec
    Nov
    etc...
Older
```

Here is what I have so far..

```
    Dim StartYear As DateFormat = Date.Now.Year
    Dim EndYear As DateFormat = Date.Now.Year - 2

    ltlArchives.Text = "<ul id=""ArchivesYears"">"
    For StartYear = StartYear To EndYear Step -1
        ltlArchives.Text = ltlArchives.Text + "<li>" + StartYear.ToString + "</li>"
    Next
    ltlArchives.Text = ltlArchives.Text + "<li>Other</li>"
    ltlArchives.Text = ltlArchives.Text + "</ul>"
```

I can carry on with this adding in the for loops for months nested under each year however it doesn't seem very practical and will generate links for months even if there are no news item entries...

Is there a way I can build this tree automatically and only include the years/months that have news entries. I can pull a list of SQL Server timestamps from the DB for all the news items and then would like to populate the list based on that...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out years and months with news item from SQL Server - say using distinct query. For example, assuming `PostedDate` column indicates entry date for new item

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   datepart(year, n.PostedDate) as Year,
   datepart(month, n.PostedDate) as Month,
FROM
   dbo.NewsItem n
ORDER BY
   Year desc, Month desc
```

This query will give you years and months that have news items. Now bind it with say repeater control to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could select out the distinct year, month values from the database and have the query order it for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR, DateCreated), DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated)  
FROM [Blah]
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

When you loop thru the result remember the "previous year" in a variable and only display the year if it has changed (i.e. `previousYear` doesn't equal the row you are looking at)

Some simple code using a fictional `YearMonth` class just for demonstration

```
dim ltlArchives as string
ltlArchives = "<ul id=""ArchivesYears"">"

dim prevYear as Int32 = 0
For Each month as YearMonth in months
    If (prevYear <> month.Year) Then
        ltlArchives = ltlArchives + "<li>" + month.Year.ToString() + "</li>"
    End If
    ltlArchives = ltlArchives + "<li>" + month.Month.ToString() + "</li>"
    prevYear = month.Year
Next

ltlArchives = ltlArchives + "</ul>"
```